# How to use @ngrx/effects with simple http call?

Tags: angular6, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a very simple http service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

import { JsOrder } from '../stores/models/order';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OrderService {
    private ordersUrl = `${environment.httpApiUrl}/orders`;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    fetchOrders(): Observable<JsOrder[]> {
        return this.http.get<JsOrder[]>(this.ordersUrl);
    }
}
```

I am trying to call it from @ngrx/effects (based on several examples on the web):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, Effect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { FETCH_ORDERS, LoadOrders } from '../actions';
import { JsOrder, Order } from '../models/order';
import { OrderService } from '../../services/order.service';

@Injectable()
export class OrderEffects {
    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private orderService: OrderService
    ) {}

    @Effect()
    fetchOrders$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(FETCH_ORDERS),
        switchMap(() => {
            return this.orderService
                .fetchOrders()
                .map((jsOrders: JsOrder[]) => {  <---- compilation error here
                    const orders = jsOrders.map(jsOrder =>
                        Order.create(jsOrder)
                    );
                    return new LoadOrders(orders);
                });
        })
    );
}
```

However I am getting a compilation error on the `.map()` call above:

> error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'

What's the correct way to do this?

P.S. I also tried to `subscribe()` to the Observable returned by the http service (see below), but that too gives a compile error (property 'map' does not exist on type 'Subscription'):

```
@Effect()
fetchOrders$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(FETCH_ORDERS),
    switchMap(() => {
        return this.orderService
            .fetchOrders()
            .subscribe((jsOrders: JsOrder[]) => {
                return jsOrders.map(jsOrder => Order.create(jsOrder));
            })
            .map((orders: Order[]) => new LoadOrders(orders));
    })
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `pipe` and the pipeable operators:

```
@Effect()
fetchOrders$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(FETCH_ORDERS),
    switchMap(() => {
        return this.orderService
            .fetchOrders()
            .pipe(
                map((jsOrders: JsOrder[]) => {  
                  const orders = jsOrders.map(jsOrder =>
                      Order.create(jsOrder)
                  );
                  return new LoadOrders(orders);
                }),
               catchError(err => of(new LoadOrdersFailure(err)))
            )
    })
);
```

Also don't forget to catch the errors.

Comment: Thanks so much, @timdeschryver. I need to brush up my rxjs skills!

Comment: can you please tell the syntax to pass parameters to the service function `fetchOrders`??

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
Meanwhile effects can be told to stop the dispatch of the next actions.

Just use the **dispatch** flag:

```
newEffect$ = createEffect(
  () => this.myAction$,
  {dispatch: false}
);
```